# SQL Server : dynamically select column based on another select column

Tags: sql-server

I would like to write a query that returns two columns. The first column would be all of the column names of an existing table (`ImportTable`) sorted alphabetically, and the second column would be a sample row from that table (`ImportTable`) showing a potential value for one of those columns.

This is the pseudo code I have so far:

```
select 
    c.name as 'Column Name', 
    (select top(1) ImportTable."c.name" 
     from Database.dbo.[ImportTable] ImportTable) as 'Sample Column Value'
from 
    Database.sys.columns c
inner join 
    Database.sys.objects o on o.object_id = c.object_id
where 
    o.name = 'ImportTable'
order by 
    c.name asc
```

I don't know how to dynamically select the column `ImportTable."c.name"` based on the value of the column name. I'm not even sure what to search for that.

Comment: You would have to build out dynamic SQL.

Comment: Reading about this now.... It makes sense for parameters passed from outside the query, but the parameter I need is returned inside of the query. Not sure how to pass that over to the second column in the select clause

Comment: There's an inherent problem with this - a column needs to have a datatype. If your first column is "ID" and an INT, then the 1st row of your record set would have an INT value as the 2nd column. If your next column is "name" with a varchar type, your 2nd row would want to return varchar type. You can cast/convert to varchar for most of these, but dates, times, floats might give you grief, and heaven help you if you have binary data.

Comment: In this case, all of my columns are varchar(50). The use case for this query is when I'm building an SSIS package to map a text file to a table, it's easier for me to just see the column in the text file with some sample data to figure out where it should go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You need to create a dynamic unpivot statement and execute it.**

Try not to get confused about what is the static and what the dynamic parts.

```sql
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = N'
SELECT v.*
FROM (
    SELECT TOP (1) *
    FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@tablename) + N'
    ORDER BY CHECKSUM(NEWID())
) t
CROSS APPLY (VALUES
' +
(
    SELECT STRING_AGG(CAST(
N'(' + QUOTENAME(c.name, '''') + N', CAST(t.' + QUOTENAME(c.name) + N' AS sql_variant))'
        AS nvarchar(max)), N',
') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY c.name ASC)
    FROM sys.columns c
    WHERE c.object_id = OBJECT_ID(@tablename)
) +
N'
) AS v(columnName, columnValue);
';

PRINT @sql;  -- for testing

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

---

If you are unfortunate enough to still be on a version not supporting `STRING_AGG`, you can use `FOR XML` instead for that part:

```sql
-------
CROSS APPLY (VALUES
' +
STUFF(
(
    SELECT N',
(' + QUOTENAME(c.name, '''') + N', CAST(t.' + QUOTENAME(c.name) + N' AS sql_variant))'
    FROM sys.columns c
    WHERE c.object_id = OBJECT_ID(@tablename)
    ORDER BY c.name ASC
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
).value('text()[1]', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 2, '') +
N'
) AS v(columnName, columnValue);
';
--------
```

Comment: No STRING_AGG on this server. The version is too old. Do you know what I can replace that with?

Comment: This code is throwing an error: "Separator parameter for STRING_AGG must be a string literal or variable."

Comment: @BrianStork Works now I think

Comment: This made sense once I realized that the SQL inside of the string "sql" is being executed first. It's two executions: one to generate the cross apply column names and another to get the first row and cross apply those to the column names from the first execution. Marking this one as correct but I think @BrianStork has an easier to understand solution.

Comment: Dynamic SQL is confusing as you need to keep track of what is static and what is dynamic. If you look at the editor you will see it has formatted the dynamic part as a string. Also you should use `PRINT` to get the resulting SQL and check it is correct

Answer (score 0):

With a little dynamic SQL, you can get this done with just a series of UNION selects. This doesn't require string_agg or any recent SQL feature.

```
declare @table sysname = N'schema.YourTableName';

-- Begin with a CTE to select 1 row at random:
declare @stmt nvarchar(max) = N'with cte as (select top(1)* from ' + @table + ' order by newid())';

-- Create string of UNION selects:
select @stmt = @stmt
     + 'select '''
     + name
     + ''' as ColumnName, cast('
     + name
     + ' as varchar(max)) as SampleValue from cte union '
from sys.columns
where object_id = object_id(@table)

-- Remove the trailing "union"
set @stmt = left(@stmt,len(@stmt)-5);

-- Add the ORDER
set @stmt = @stmt + ' order by ColumnName';

-- Execute the query:
exec sp_executesql @stmt = @stmt;
```

Comment: This works. I didn't know you could append a string with each row returned in the select clause. Interesting way to solve this problem. I'm not sure what the proper etiquette is on stackoverflow. @Charlieface also provided a detailed answer before you posted. Tough decision on which answer to mark correct

Comment: I know, right? That Select-to-concatenate-a-string was new to me a few years ago - thought for sure it wouldn't work. The solution by @Charlieface is more elegant and a few milliseconds faster than mine.

Comment: @rallen "Select-to-concatenate-a-string" as Brian calls it, is not guaranteed to work properly. In particular it falls down in the face of an `order by` or parallelism. Grouped Concatenation should only be done with `STRING_AGG` or `FOR XML/JSON`

Comment: For this example, the `order by` isn't important in the concatenation, only in the final select. `STRING_AGG` is the bomb if you have it. The `for xml` is lightning fast and can guarantee order, but this simple select is quick to write and easy to remember. I almost always have to look up examples of the `for xml` method. As a quick, simple solution, it gets the job done. Though I agree, it's not as optimal as other solutions.